# Why does GANTracker outputs an error "GANTracker.m" not found?

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-analytics

I have used the Google Analytics Tracker in a previous iPhone OS project. Everything was working fine and I copy & pasted the GANTracker Library and the Tracker initialization.

When starting my new project it tells me:

> Xcode could not locate source file:
>   GANTracker.m (line: 177)

To tell the truth, I don't know where to start to debug this one.

I have included the library using `#import "GANTracker.h"`.

The error message occurs right within the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and does not seem to have any connection to what is really going on. If I set the breakpoint to `[window makeKeyAndVisible];` for example and wait a second, it occurs right after that. That makes it look like there is something in the background going on with the GANTracker.

The Tracker itself is created a little later by:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"xx" dispatchPeriod:10 delegate:nil];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"pageview" withError:nil];
```

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Look up line 177 of `GANTracker.m`. What's it say?

Comment: There is none, because it is within the precompiled library and I cant access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it with some guesswork:

I was assuming that the error parameter can be nil, doing:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"somePageView" withError:nil];
```

But error can not be nil:

```
NSError *error;
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"somePageView" withError:&error];
```

This fixed it. Still, this doesn't add up because the crash was not at that line, but it fixed it.

Comment: The crash was where GANTracker tried to assign a value to the nil you were passing as error, which we can assume is line 177.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to commenting this. But how can this error happen if the line is not beeing called? I have set a breakpoint two lines before and got the same error message?

Comment: I know this post is old, but can you tell me how did you manage to solve it actually ?
I have corrected like your answer, however i still get the error. But i clean all targets and re-run it i dont get the error.

Comment: I moved to always use an NSError variable, never giving nil as parameter :)